# My laptop can't share a printer with my PC

Tags: windows-vista, printer

I have a Belkin wireless router and all devices including my laptop can connect to the internet.  However I can't get my laptop running on Windows XP to connect to my printer through my PC running on Windows Vista. I read all the posts but nothing works. I get an error message on my laptop saying 'The name of my network' doesn't give me permission.  How do I change this?

Comment: Can you ping your PC from your laptop?  Can you connect to a file share on your PC from your laptop?

Answer (score 3):

In Vistas "Network Sharing Center" there are specific options for file sharing, password protected file sharing and printer sharing. Look for the "Password protected sharing" under " Sharing and Discovery" and turn it off.

Comment: I'd run into this like twice because I'm so XP-user, and when I updated to vista, could not share anything until I found this option. It's weird that vista and 7 don't let you share those even if you select HOME NETWORK as your network location. Great Answer

Answer (score 0):

What about your AV protection - I know (becasuse I worked there) Kaspersky Internet Security 2009 blocks printer sharing, or any kind of network sharing by default.

Although Adam's answer seems like the solution in this case.